# Concat multiple results with left join not working

Tags: sql, database

In my project I have a user table with regular information such as name, age, and the phone numbers are listed on another table with a relationship table to connect them.

Something like this.

```
TBL_User (name, dateofbirth, mail)
TBL_PhoneType (id, phonetype) //like, cellphone, home phone, etc.
TBL_PhoneNumber (id, phonetype, phonenuber) //lists muliple values for each user
TBL_PhoneRelation (userid, pnid)
```

I'm trying to make a selection to return the user information and a CONCAT version of the phone numbers, but the problem is the result that I get.

My first try is the GROUP_CONCAT, something like

```
SELECT us.name, us.dateofbirth, GROUP_CONCAT(' ', pt.phonetype, ' ', p.phonenumber) 
FROM TBL_User AS us 
LEFT JOIN TBL_PhoneRelation AS pr ON pr.userid = us.id 
LEFT JOIN TBL_PhoneNumber AS p ON p.id = pr.pnid
```

The problem is that I get only one row and not all the values from the database and a regular CONCAT show only one phone number, and sub selection gives a error because I have more than 1 row in my result.

I'm trying something like this

```
User name | Phone number                             | E-mail
Adrian    | Cellphone 11..., Home phone 22...        | adrian...
Suzan     | Cellphone 32..., Commercial phone 44...  | sue...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
select
    U.Name,
    group_concat(', ', T.PhoneType + ' ' + N.PhoneNumber)
    U.Mail
from
    TBL_user as U
left join 
    TBL_PhoneRelation AS R ON 
        R.UserID = U.ID
LEFT JOIN 
    TBL_PhoneNumber AS N ON 
        N.ID = R.PhoneID
left join
    TBL_PhoneType as T on
        T.ID = N.PhoneTypeID
group by
    U.Name
```

Comment: Fits like a glove, but with a group by id.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    U.Name,
    group_concat(CONCAT(T.PhoneType + ' ' + N.PhoneNumber) SEPARATOR ','),
    U.Mail
from
    TBL_user as U
left join 
    TBL_PhoneRelation AS R ON R.UserID = U.ID
LEFT JOIN 
    TBL_PhoneNumber AS N ON N.ID = R.PhoneID
left join
    TBL_PhoneType as T on T.ID = N.PhoneTypeID
group by
    U.ID
```

Comment: Not sure if it is a MariaDB issue, but I got a 0,0,0,0 like result with this concat.