# how to select multiple values and concat?

Tags: sql, concatenation, pgadmin

[image]when I try to concat 2 values which is being selected from 2 different values, I am getting this synatax error.please help

Comment: As per [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please post text, not images, of code. Also, for a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), include both sample data (again, as text that is code) and desired results. As it stands, what you're trying to do isn't clear. Also also, joins are generally preferred over sub-selects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concat multiple results with left join not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976724/concat-multiple-results-with-left-join-not-working)

Comment: I can't copy-and-paste that code... Use formatted text instead of images the next time.